# Limiting distribution of a squared sum of random variables

Tags: central-limit-theorem, delta-method

Let $S_n = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$, and $T_n = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^nY_i$, where

The $X_i$ are iid, the $Y_i$ are iid (with a different law)

$X_i$, and $Y_i$ are dependent

For $i\neq j$, $X_i$ and $Y_j$ are independent.

Is there a central limit type result for $S_n^2 - T_n^2$?

Comment: Whether $E(X_1)=\pm E(Y_1)$ or not would yield quite different results. And a hypothesis more precise than "$X_i$ and $Y_i$ are dependent" might be needed. (Duplicate from math.stackexchange... You might want to choose one of the two sites and stick to it.)

Comment: @Ian Langmore, I've answered the question in math.SE (http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/19274/limiting-distribution-of-a-squared-sum-of-random-variables/19351#19351)

Comment: hm, what is the usual practice for questions duplicated in two SE sites? Should I post the answer in both sites, and then gather the feedback from two different communities?

Comment: @mpiktas Just flag it for mod attention (which is what I've done)

Comment: @chl, judging from the number of votes this question is more interesting to statisticians :)

Comment: @chl, mpiktas This question is certainly in-scope here, even if it is an exact duplicate on another site.  In fact, it's probably more relevant to our community than the other one.  I'm inclined to suggest that we leave it open?

Comment: @Shane @mpiktas @Didier It seems more appropriate here (IMHO). Maybe @Ian Langmore could close it on math.SE so that @mpiktas can move his response there?

Comment: My initial thought was to close this question, but as @Shane points out, it is particularly relevant for statisticians. @mpiktas do you want to answer the question (again?)

Comment: @mpiktas: It's usual for a question to only appear on a single site. But I think their should be some flexibility to this rule.

Comment: @csgillespie, ok, I am reposting my answer here. Maybe we should notify moderators of math.SE to close the question there?

Comment: Sorry for the duplicate question...I'm claiming newbie over-enthusiasm...In any case, if people agree that the question is better on stats.SE, I happy with it being closed on math.SE.  Not sure if I can do this though...I could vote to delete it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $X_i$ and $Y_j$ are dependent for $i=j$, but independent for  $i\neq j$ we have an iid sample from bivariate distribution $Z_i=(X_i,Y_i)$. Then central limit theorem gives us

\begin{align}
\sqrt{n}\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nZ_i -EZ_1\right)\xrightarrow{D}N(0,\Sigma)
\end{align}
with $\Sigma=cov(Z_1)$ and $\xrightarrow{D}$ indicating convergence in distribution. Note that

$$(S_n,T_n)=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nZ_i.$$

Now we can use delta method, which states that if $r_n(U_n-\theta)\xrightarrow{D}U$ for numbers $r_n\to\infty$, then $r_n(\phi(U_n)-\phi(\theta))\xrightarrow{D}\phi'_\theta(U)$. This statement can be found [here](http://books.google.com/books?id=UEuQEM5RjWgC&lpg=PR1&dq=asymptotic%20statistics%20vaart&hl=fr&pg=PA26#v=onepage&q&f=false). Delta method is also described [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_method).

In our case now we have $r_n=\sqrt{n}$, $\phi(x,y)=x^2-y^2$, $U_n=(S_n,T_n)$ and $\theta=(EX_1,EY_1)$. We have

$$\phi_{\theta}'=(2EX_1,-2EY_1)$$

and

$$U=(U_1,U_2)\sim N(0,\Sigma)$$

Finally we get

\begin{align}
\sqrt{n}\left(S_n^2-T_n^2-(EX_1)^2+(EY_1)^2\right)\xrightarrow{D} 
2U_1EX_1-2U_2EY_1:=V
\end{align}

Since we know that $(U_1,U_2)\sim N(0,\Sigma)$ we get that

$$V\sim N(0,4(EX_1,EY_1)\Sigma(EX_1,EY_1)').$$

Note that I basically redid the example after the theorem in the link.

The final answer then depends on $\Sigma=cov((X_1,Y_1))$, but this should be known to original poster.

Comment: @Ian Langmore, you are welcome, I had some fun in answering it. If this answer was useful, you might want to accept it, this is the way this site works. To cite the [faq](http://stats.stackexchange.com/faq) you can accept the answer by clicking on the check box outline to the left of the answer.